# Deserialize part of SOAP response

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-namespaces

I am a bit lost with the deserialization of a particular part of my soap response.

The response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:LoginResult xmlns:ns1="http://abc.def.schema">
        <sessionId>123456789</sessionId>
        <sessionTimeout>30</sessionTimeout>
        <organizationName>WebService Test Account XYZ</organizationName>
        <userInfoResult>
            <accessibleOrgs>
                <name>WebService Test Account XYZ</name>
                <description/>
                <prefix>10</prefix>
                <countryCallingCode>+49</countryCallingCode>
                <treeLevel>0</treeLevel>
                <timeZone>
                    <timeZoneId>Europe/Berlin</timeZoneId>
                    <currentUtcOffset>3600000</currentUtcOffset>
                </timeZone>
                <billingCompany>COMPANY 123</billingCompany>
                <language>DE</language>
            </accessibleOrgs>
            <isDemo>true</isDemo>
            <prefixLength>0</prefixLength>
            <alarmNumberLength>0</alarmNumberLength>
            <groupNumberLength>0</groupNumberLength>
            <personNumberLength>0</personNumberLength>
        </userInfoResult>
    </ns1:LoginResult>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I need to deserialize the "LoginResult" part. I am aware of deserialization methods but I am struggling with the fact that A) there are namespaces and B) I just need a subset of the XML.

Maybe somebody could point me into the right direction.

Thx in advcance

Comment: What subset of the xml?

Comment: As mentioned in my post I need the Part "LoginResult". But I'll check the suggestion of EyIM, will give feedback :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with definition of LoginResult class.

```
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://abc.def.schema", IsNullable = false, ElementName = "LoginResult")]
public class LoginResult
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace ="")]
    public int sessionId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public string organizationName { get; set; }

     ..... some more properties
}
```

1. Use [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8) class from `System.Xml.Linq` to parse the xml.
2. Find the "LoginResult" element.
3. Deserialize as `LoginResult` type.

   ```
   var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
   var xLoginResult = xDoc.Root.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name.LocalName.Equals("LoginResult"));
   var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LoginResult));
   using (var reader = xLoginResult.CreateReader())
   {                
       var result = (LoginResult)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
   }
   ```